# How can I call function from a map?

Tags: c++, function, pointers, dictionary

I want to know how can I (if I even can) output(call) the functionality from a function. I want to have the 1, UP output. Its a new task from my mentor. Practicing callback functionality in real life examples. (im starting to create a little game).

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <map>

using namespace std;


void up (){

    cout<<"UP";
}

void down (){

    cout<<"DOWN";
}

void left (){

    cout<<"LEFT";
}
void right (){

    cout<<"RIGHT";
}


int main (){

   typedef map<int, void (*)()> mapaF;

    mapaF Kretnje;

    Kretnje.insert(pair<int,void (*)() >(1, up));
//    Kretnje.insert(pair<int, void (*)()>(2, down));
//    Kretnje.insert(pair<int, void (*)()>(3, left));
//    Kretnje.insert(pair<int, void (*)()>(4, right));

    for(auto a: Kretnje){
        cout<<"Kljuc: "<<a.first<<", Funkcija: "<<a.second<<endl;

    }
    //output 1, 1(?))
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: We call functions with `()` operator.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use the same function call syntax `()` on it.

```
for (auto a : Kretnje)
    a.second(); //UP
```

Keep in mind that calling the function returns `void`, so you can't call it in a `cout` chain.

```
std::cout << a.first << a.second(); //error, a.second() is void
```

Comment: I suspect that those functions are only placeholders, otherwise you can suggest that the easiest way to fix the problem with the return value is to change them into something like: `std::string up( ){ return  "UP"; }`